# Security of AWS configuration details with environment.ts file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, security, ionic-framework, aws-amplify

I got an AWS Amplify project for the first time. But I have worked on many Firebase projects. My question here is the security of AWS configuration details.

We normally put Firebase configurations on the `environment.ts` file and no issues for security there. But how about AWS Amplify configurations here with the `environment.ts` file? Is that secured or do I need to remove it from `environment.ts`

AWS Amplify file config is like so:

```
const config= {
    "aws_project_region": "",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "",
    "aws_cognito_region": "",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "",
    "oauth": {}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the `aws-exports.js` file that amplify creates when we initialize the project. We add this file to `.gitignore` so its not committed to version control. Unlike firebase, we don't need to share this file with all developers. This file will be generated by amplify cli whenever a developer sets up the amplify project on his machine.

So the flow goes like this:

1. A new developer can clone your amplify project repo (which contains amplify folder)
2. Run `amplify configure` to login with correct aws account and create credentials for CLI.
3. Run `amplify init` to select the profile you create in previous step and then select the existing amplify project on that aws account. This will automatically create that aws-exports file for that particular developer.

Thus you won't ever need to share this file with anyone and it'll be secure.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But when the application is hosted, you will be able to find the configuration in bundle files. So is it secure?